# Prevent to import CommonModule while creating new component by Angular 17 CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How can I prevent CommonModule from being added to imports array in component generated by Angular 17 CLI? I can't find an option to add in angular.json to `@schematics/angular:component`.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-new-component',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule], <---- I want this array to be empty while generate new component by "ng g c new-component"
    templateUrl: './new-component.component.html',
    styleUrl: './new-component.component.scss',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class NewComponentComponent {}
```

The lack of `imports` property satisfies me as well as empty `imports` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change has already landed [in CLI the repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/571722d2a9098497c80438467814de62f84e382b) and will be available in 17.1

Until then, you can't do much beside doing the change yourself in the `node_modules` and use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).